# External links from fancybox is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox

PHP

```
$profile_url = $vars['url'].'pg/profile/'.$user->username;
```

HTML

```
<div style='float:left;margin-top:8px;margin-right:-3px;'><a href='#edit_profile' class='apply_alert' id='{$job_id}'><span class='apply_button'></span></a></div>

<div id="edit_profile">
    <div style="background:#fff;height:100%;border:1px solid #1583D0;">

        <div style="padding:20px 10px 10px;">
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo $profile_url?>" class="profile_btn button-blue">Edit profile</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(".apply_alert").fancybox({
        'titlePosition' : 'inside',
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'frameWidth'  : 420,           // set the width
        'frameHeight' : 175
        });
```

I have an fancybox. Inside that i am adding a link to a button.

The problem i am facing is the url i am referring in anchor tag in a fancybox is not working. When i click the button the popup is just getting fading down. How to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution just set `hideOnContentClick` to `false` in your fancybox script...here its will work...